# Error en servidor de mail Postfix- Dovecot

Tags: mysql

Tengo este error en **mail.log**:

> corpocar postfix/trivial-rewrite[2324]: warning: do not list domain
>   corpocar.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains

Pero borre mi dominio de `mydestination`, saqué localhost, saque todo. No se si hice bién.

mydestination en **main.cf**:

```
mydestination = $virtual_mailbox_domains
```

También me salta este error :

> corpocar postfix/qmgr[2034]: warning: connect to transport
>   private/virtuales: No such file or directory

A la tabla que se llamaba `virtual` le llame `virtuales` pero creo que el error se refiere a ésto:

```
create table transport ( domain varchar(128) not null primary key unique, transport varchar(128) not null default 'virtuales:' );
```

La verdad que me quede trabado. Aquí les paso el log entero de mi servidor:

> May 17 16:27:06 corpocar postfix/trivial-rewrite[2324]: warning: do
>   not list domain corpocar.com in BOTH mydestination and
>   virtual_mailbox_domains
>
> May 17 16:27:06 corpocar postfix/smtpd[2321]: C4BBD1A00618:
>   client=mail-yb0-f182.google.com[209.85.213.182]
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/cleanup[2325]: C4BBD1A00618:
>   message-id=
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/qmgr[2034]: C4BBD1A00618:
>   from=, size=2440, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/trivial-rewrite[2324]: warning: do
>   not list domain corpocar.com in BOTH mydestination and
>   virtual_mailbox_domains
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/qmgr[2034]: warning: connect to
>   transport private/virtuales: No such file or directory
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/error[2327]: C4BBD1A00618:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=0.52,
>   delays=0.45/0.03/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail$
>
> May 17 16:27:07 corpocar postfix/smtpd[2321]: disconnect from
>   mail-yb0-f182.google.com[209.85.213.182] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1
>   quit=1 commands=5

Comment: Pablito Maugeri, te recomiendo que intentes redactar la pregunta de una forma clara, fácil de leer y entender. Después de redactarla es oportuno releerla para ver si nos ha quedado algo comprensible. Por otro lado intenta dar el formato apropiado al código y a los errores, los seleccionas y usa los botones correspondientes del editor (**`{}`** o Ctrl+k y  **`“`**)para que queden correctamente formateados. Esto facilita la lectura y la comprensión de tu problema, y por consiguiente, el recibir buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: perdón desde ya muchas gracias